# Input and output from excel to cpp project

Tags: c++, database, excel, fstream

I need to find a way to read and write to excel cells like fstream when u read/write into a text file. I tried using `<fstream>` but it only fills Cell A1 and maybe A2 if I use endl or \n. I would like to know if there is a way to access other cells so I can fill them with values to make a database for a project. Values like, Names, Telephones, Price, etc.

```
fstream file;
file.open("file.csv", ios::out | ios::app | ios::in);
if(!file.is_open())
{
 cout << "Error!\n";
}
else
{
 file << "Text1\nText2";
}
file.close();
```

Comment: Do you want the entire code or just the part with the issue?

Comment: Just the part that is relevant to the question - reading and writing to the file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using csv = comma separated values. To put values on different columns separate them with a comma - ,

```
file << "v1" << ',' << "v2";
```

**EDIT**
just found [this](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Import-or-export-text-txt-or-csv-files-5250ac4c-663c-47ce-937b-339e391393ba) that states the default delimiter is TAB (`\t`), so you should use:

```
file << "v1" << '\t' << "v2";
```

it also has instruction on how to change this.

Comment: There is the problem, when I use that comma, cell A1 value is v1,v2 and B2 is empty.

Comment: Still the same, I will read the link u posted now and maybe I hope I can find something

Comment: When I open excel manual and set a value to A1 and the press tab It goes to B1 but I don't know why it doesn't work with \t.

Answer (score 0):

Its not a trivial task to read/write and format an excel file. You can try using [libxl](http://www.libxl.com/)

**Alternately**
save your excel file as a .csv and then read and write to it. csvs are comma separated files where data in each column is separated by a comma and each row by a new line.

**update**
csv files can be created using any simple text editor like notepad. Just separate the data using commas

**update 2**

```
 file <<"Text1,"<<"Text2,"<<std::endl; //row 1
 file <<"Text3,"<<"Text4,"<<std::endl;  // row 2
```

**Update 3**

```
int main()
{
    ofstream out("C:\\inp.csv");

    out << "Text1,Text2" << endl;   
    out << "Text1,Text2" << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I tried that and Cell A1 has the value Text1,Text2 and Cell A2 has the value Text3,Text4.

Comment: take a look at my code posted under update 3. Works fine for me. I see Text1 in A1, A2 and Text2 in B1, B2

Comment: Still the same :/, the only thing I can think of is excel has a problem, because I cracked Microsoft office 2016 3 days ago. I'm sorry I'm wasting your time, Ill find an other way :/ Thanks anyway